# Vim: Change Max Line from 80 in pymode

Tags: python, vim

I'm using the plugin [Python-Mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode), which has an PymodeLintAuto feature which 'Fix PEP8 errors in current buffer automatically'. I was wondering how I could change the max line length for that was. I couldn't find in the [docs](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/develop/doc/pymode.txt#L253)

Comment: None of those answer works ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Python-Mode is using PyLint, you can specify what errors you wish for it to raise. This involves creating a customised `pylint.rc` and then giving that to `pymode` using a setting in your `.vimrc`.

.vimrc:

```
" Pylint configuration file
let g:pymode_lint_config = '$HOME/pylint.rc'
```

pylint.rc:

```
[FORMAT]

# Maximum number of characters on a single line.
max-line-length=120
```

Comment: This is totally awesome! Thanks for answering.  However is there also a way to adjust the visual 80 character limit indicator? That's still there even though it no longer warns until I'm over 120.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore, because the option `pymode_lint_config` is removed at the version `0.7.8b` in 2013-12-04. Check [the changelog](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/develop/Changelog.rst)

Answer (score 13):

To change max line length in pymode you change

```
g:pymode_options_max_line_length
```

with `let`.

However this does not work for me, so do as [@dillbert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353692/4284367) suggested.
For the colorbar:

```
autocmd FileType python set colorcolumn=120
```

in your .vimrc

Answer (score 9):

In recent (as of June 2018) python-mode versions, the required configuration seems to be this:

```
let g:pymode_options_max_line_length = 88
let g:pymode_lint_options_pep8 = {'max_line_length': g:pymode_options_max_line_length}
let g:pymode_options_colorcolumn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above answers, but none works, I have to write hard code the python-mode. Here is my solution:

Find `pep8.py` in your .vim, my is under `/Users/chaopeng/.vim/bundle/Python-mode-klen/pylibs/pylama/pep8.py`, then replace `79` with `119` in `pep8.py`.

And don't miss

```
let g:pymode_options_max_line_length=120
autocmd FileType python set colorcolumn=120
```